# Use custom type in JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

One have the following JSON object:

```
{
  "index": 10,
  "data": "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>..."
}
```

the corresponding schema:

```
{
  "title": "Example",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "index": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "data": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to validate XML inside `data` property with XSD schema.

How to represent XML data type with xsd schema attribute correctly from the point of JSON Schema specs?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**

You can't

**Long answer**

You really can't. No JSON processor in the history of mankind will be able to validate inline XML against an XSD.

The only thing you can do is include the XSD file as text and then the consumer of the JSON can then do the validation on their side. Or, even better, validate the XML before you place it in the JSON doc.